# Bluetooth module HC-06 is not responding to any AT command on Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, at-command

Arduino Uno R3, HC-06. There's no response to the AT commands on the serial monitor.

I want to establish Bluetooth communication between PC and Arduino. At first I had to change the baud rate from 9600 to 115200, and the AT+BAUD8 command was working well. But after that change AT commands are not working. I cannot see any respond on the serial monitor.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(2, 3); // Bluetooth module Tx:Digital 2 Rx:Digital 3

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ATcommand");  //ATcommand Start
}

void loop() {
  if (BTSerial.available())
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

I used the above simple code and also I've already checked the Tx, Rx pins.

What I want to do in the end is Bluetooth communication with a PC as a master and an Arduino as a slave.

Is it possible to upload code to Arduino through Bluetooth?

Comment: If you changed your baudrate to 115200, you probably should change `BTSerial.begin(9600)` to `BTSerial.begin(115200)`, right? Or did you already try that?

Comment: @KarstenKoop Yes I already try that but it doesn't work

Comment: I read somewhere that SoftwareSerial does not reliably support 115200, maybe that's simply the reason. Can you do a factory reset of the HC-06 to go back to 9600?

Comment: [Here they say it can do 57600 at best](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=339644.0)

Comment: I think I can't do a factory reset of HC-06...  @KarstenKoop

Comment: Solved by add Serial.println("AT+BAUD4"); in setup()

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial BT(10,11); // TX to pin_10. RX to pin_11 of Arduino.
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      BT.begin(9600);
    }
    
    void loop() {
        if(Serial.available()) {   
        String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(command); 
        BT.print(command);
        }
     
       if (BT.available()){
       String retorno = BT.readStringUntil('\n');
       Serial.println(retorno);
       }
    }
```

Serial Monitor with New line.

```
AT
AT+VERSION
AT+NAMEmy_blue
AT+BAUDx
```